# Change language on Ionic2 - What is the most effective way to change all page language?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ng2-translate

I am trying to use [ng2-translate](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core#api) on `Ionic2` to do the multi-language, and I added a `button` for changing the language of the `Apps` on the `setting page`. Basically, the function of changing language is work on the setting page only, but the other page will not happen anything.

And I have a stupid way to do the translation, that is add a function ,which change the language of the current page, on every pages and it will be executed when I click the button on the `setting page`.

But this solution less efficiency,  how can do the same thing in a effective way?

Here is a part of my code:

1. Setting Page:

   ```
     import { Component,  ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

     import { NavController, List } from 'ionic-angular';
     import {TranslateService, TranslatePipe, TranslateLoader, TranslateStaticLoader} from 'ng2-translate/ng2-translate';
     @Component({
         selector: 'page-setting',
         templateUrl: 'setting.html'
      })

     export class SettingPage {
         translate;
        @ViewChild(List) list: List;
        constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,   translate: TranslateService) {
             translate.setDefaultLang('zh');
             this.translate = translate;
         }
          //When the translation button is clicked
          click() {
             this.translate.use('en');
                  //Change all the pages language
                  location.change('en');`enter code here`
                  home.change('en');
            }

     }
   ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i have the same, a settings page to change language.

I have this on html:

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-label class="primary-text-color">{{ 'Settings.settings.language' | translate }}</ion-label>
  <ion-select [(ngModel)]="language" (ionChange)="onChange($event)">
    <ion-option value="es">Español</ion-option>
    <ion-option value="en">English</ion-option>
  </ion-select>
</ion-item>
```

Then on my ts file:

```
import { TranslateService } from 'ng2-translate';

[...]

language: String;

constructor(public translate: TranslateService) {
    this.language = translate.currentLang;
    this.usermail = this.userdata.getEmail();
}

onChange(e) {
    this.translate.use(e);
}
```

This will change your language in all pages, just use the `{{ 'Settings.info.mail' | translate }}` pipe and it will change the translation when you pick another language with no more changes.

Hope it helps you

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I tried to use your code, and it doesn't work to me. Is it my constructor wrong?

Comment: I found out the problem. The constructor in other pages SHOULD NOT have any `TranslateService parameter. I removed all the TranslateService in other pages and it is work pretty now. Thanks a lot.